# Matlab: Convert List of 2D coordinates into "cuts" in a 3D cylindrical shape

Tags: arrays, matlab, geometry, shapes

EDIT: Here is a preamble to make it clear what I'm doing.  My overall goal is to make an STL of a cylinder (well, an approximated cylinder) that has had some holes cut through its surface.  The holes are defined as quadrilaterals with vertexes I have calculated (I can get the vertex X,Y,Z coordinates). The step I am stuck on is: I don't know how to define the cylinder geometry or the hole geometry such that I can subtract the holes from the cylinder and then be left with something that can be meshed and converted to STL.

I have an ordered list of 2D coordinates stored in the form of a 2 x N array; call it Cuts=[W(1:N);Z(1:N)], where we are defining W and Z as perpendicular axes (instead of X and Y, you'll see why in a moment).

For this list, every 6 pairs of coordinate points represent the corner vertexes of a hole.  So, the 3rd hole in the list has the corner vertex coordinates of Cuts(: , 13:18), if that makes sense:

```
Cuts = [1 1 2 3 2 2 1 1 2 3 2 2 1 1 2 3 2 2 1 1 2 3 2 2 ...;
      [0 2 3 3 2 0 10 12 13 13 12 10 20 22 23 23 22 20 ...];

Hole3w = Cuts(1 , 13:18)
Hole3z = Cuts(2 , 13:18)

output: 
Hole3w = 1 1 2 3 2 2
Hole3z = 20 22 23 23 22 20
```

The coordinates are ordered such that they are sequential going around the perimeter of each hole.  It occurs to me that I might have accidentally made half clockwise and the other half counter clockwise, but I'll fix that before implementing any suggestions here.

Now hold on, because we're about to do something silly:

I want to take this 2D list of hole vertexes, "extrude" it into a sheet with a defined thickness, "and then roll that into a vertical tube".

Now, obviously, I don't actually want to do those steps. What I mean is I want to do the numerical equivalent.  I'm going to pick a radius for the roll (call it R0), and a thickness T for the sheet (and thus an outer radius, R1 = R0 + T;)  I've already constrained the original dataset so that the largest value along the W axis is equal to the circumference of a circle of radius R0.  Thus, the workflow I'm envisioning is:

1. Z axis remains unchanged
2. The W axis is remapped to polar coordinates, so that the W coordinate is taken as the arc-length around the circle of R0, and this is used to determine the (R0, Alpha, z) coordinate of each vertex. Call this set CutPol0.
3. This is duplicated and R0 is replaced with R1, to get the vertex coordinates of the outer face. Call this set CutPol1.
4. The polar coordinates of CutPol0 and CutPol1 are then used to calculate the X/Y coordinates of each, getting me the cartesian set, named as CutCart0 and CutCart1.

I get all of this, and I can likely do everything up to this point no problem.  Here's where I am not sure how to proceed.  Currently, I just have 2 sets of 3D cartesian coordinates that are essentially just two layers of point clouds.  I understand that each R0 vertex is connected to its R1 partner, and that in each set the perimeter of the hole is connected along those 6 perimeter points.  What I don't know is:

1. How do I tell the program they are connected?
2. I want these as, essentially, holes cut through the annular surface of a pipe. This means there's a surface between the holes, which I haven't defined yet.  How do I do this?  How do I make the surface as cylindrical as I can?

I can see a useful answer about everything after that point (then taking the surface xyz and converting it to an STL).  I just don't know how to take what I have and convert it to a surface geometry that could be STL'd.

For reference, the number and size of holes is variable, but it's as many as 6000 (36000 points per surface).

I genuinely haven't tried anything here yet.  I have the 2D (w,z) array plotted and it looks correct, but I'm not sure how to define the surface these holes are "cut" out of, or how the the connections of the vertexes are defined.

Comment: It would be worth editing your q to make it more specific. What exactly are you trying to do? Is it to generate an STL file with the vertices defining the holes (it appears there is no simple way to model curved surfaces in STLs - maybe you would need to use a discrete polygonal approximation)? Or something else? In any case, is this helpful: `Hole3w = [1 1 2 3 2 2]; Hole3z = [20 22 23 23 22 20]; R = 20; Hole3x = R*cos(Hole3w/R); Hole3y = R*sin(Hole3w/R); figure; scatter3(Hole3x, Hole3y, Hole3z); k = boundary(Hole3x.', Hole3y.', Hole3z.'); hold on; trimesh(k, Hole3x.', Hole3y.', Hole3z.');`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @magnesium - I'm not sure how to be more clear, but I'll do my best to edit in a preamble.  1) yes, I know I can't do curves in an STL, I'm more asking how do I generate a volume definition for a cylinder, and "cut out" the holes I've defined? After that, the problem is just "triangulate into a mesh for STL".
2) I'm not clear what you just did with that boundary command, but I suspect that's exactly what I need, so I'll go read up on it.  Thank you!

Comment: Even just a simple case like "generate a cylinder" (without a hole) - what would that look like? How would the data be represented? A parametric representation? A vertex/mesh representation? Something else?